# How do I deploy a Page Manager page using code?

Tags: features, panels

I've created a Page Manager page using a Panels layout and a single Variant to act as the desired page. I'd like to store the settings in code for deployment to a different server.

Using Features to export the Page Manager (page_manager_pages) component appears to have done this, however the newly deployed page variant's content tab is empty. The page settings have come through, but the page contents don't show up, even though they're clearly in the featurized module code. The desired content for the page variant is in the file myModule.pages_default.inc, in the function myModule_default_page_manager_pages().

The result upon deployment is that the Page Manager page is created, and appears in /admin/structure/pages, but the Content tab for the page variant is empty. I need the code the provide the many blocks I placed, configured, and saved within the development environment.

I've also tried exporting the entire page or just the variant and importing that, and get exactly the same results.

What code or step am I missing, please?

My setup:

- Drupal 7.52
- Panels 7.x-3.6
- Page Manager 7.x-1.9
- Features 7.x-2.10

Answer (score 0):

aha. This problem was caused by a forgotten dependency within the Page Manager page. Instead of using a default layout such as 'two column,' I'd used the Bootstrap layout provided by the [Panels Bootstrap Layouts](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels_bootstrap_layouts), and then forgot about it. Features didn't add Panels Bootstrap Layouts as a dependency, it remained disabled after deployment, and the dependent page content didn't show. After I enabled Panels Bootstrap Layouts, the content items showed right up within the variant's Content tab.

So if your feature or your Panels/Pages import doesn't recreate the entire setup, review the original for any options that might be provided by another module.